# Using SVM after feature extraction for Nudity Detection Algorithm

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

**Nudity Detection Algorithm**

- normalization
- Zoning
- Feature Extraction
- Classification using SVM

Following methods are use

**1.Normalization**: First image is converted into .jpg format and size of 256X256.Then it is converted into YCbCr color space,for this i use OpenCV python.Here is the **code**.

**2.Zoning**: Normalized Images are then divided into three zones.It is because assumption is "Nudity of images are found mostly in Central zone".

**3.Feature Extraction**: In this module Image is in YCbCr,Skin pixels are filtered by thresholding in range **(0,133,77),(255,173,127)** and divided into three zones.and then for each zones features are calculated 2 color features(number of connected skin pixels and proportion of skin pixel to total pixel) and 2 texture features(Homogeneity and correlation).texture features are calculated using glcm (skimage.features module).here is the **code**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import cv
import skimage.feature as sf
total_pixels=256.0*256.0

class normalize:
    def __init__(self,src,dst):
        self.src=src
        self.dst=dst+"_1.jpg"
    def resize(self):
        x,y=256,256
        src=cv2.imread(self.src,1)
        src=cv2.resize(src,(x,y))
        cv2.imwrite(self.dst,src)
        dst=cv2.imread(self.dst,1)
        return dst
"""Segmentation module is used to segment out skin pixels in YCrCb color space"""

def segmentation(src):
    img=src.copy()
    img=cv2.cvtColor(src,cv.CV_BGR2YCrCb)
    dst=cv2.inRange(img,(0,133,77),(255,173,127))
    return dst

"""Image Zoning and feature extraction module"""

class features:
    def __init__(self,src):
        self.zone1=src
        self.zone2=src[30:226,30:226]
        self.zone3=src[60:196,60:196]

    def createglcm(self,zone):
        return sf.greycomatrix(zone,[1],[0,np.pi/4,np.pi/2,-np.pi/2,-np.pi/4,np.pi*25/12],normed=True)

    def getCorrelation(self,glcm):
        return sf.greycoprops(glcm,'correlation')

    def getHomogeneity(self,glcm):
        return sf.greycoprops(glcm,'homogeneity')

    def getcolorfeatures(self,zone):
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(zone,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        skin_pixel_connected=0 

        for i in range(len(contours)):
            skin_pixel_connected=skin_pixel_connected+cv2.contourArea(contours[i])

        return [skin_pixel_connected,skin_pixel_connected/total_pixels]
```

Now i have retrieved a list of various features as given in code. How to make feature vector for svm from python lists.How to use SVM for training by using nude and non-nude image(i have 5000 images) and then for detection.? Can any body suggest me.

Comment: You might want to reduce the question in size. I feel you have a legitimate issue, but right now there are lots of irrelevant information here.

Comment: You will need to provide face images as negative examples, or you could use a face detector to eliminate false positives on faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cross-validation strategy,C=100.00 and gamma=0.07

this is what my code looks:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier=SVC(kernel='rbf',C=100.0,gamma=0.07,cache_size=800)
classifier.fit(np.array(featurespace),np.array(classes))
classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You create a SVM the objekt.
2. Train your SVM, using the fit method with your training picture.
3. Use the predict method to predict on your test/data.

code:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X,y)
clf.predict(X_test)
```

For the feature Vector X simply merge your features into one np array for every train data.

Comment: i have to use this classifier in web application,.how to do that?

Comment: depends on your web app. if its already existing there possibilites to call your python script inside of php (for example) if you write a new web app you might wanna look for example into django or flask.